# Google search console

Tags: google-search-console, blog

I am facing this problem on my samakal blog
Google search console is showing this message "URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'BN' that do not have return tags." How can I fix it easily?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear, too specific and likely duplicate.